# override value of instance variable based on user string

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am building a java based web app with a class (being created per request) that does some computation based on configured member variables. I want to make it possible for the user to experiment by changing the value of any of these instance variables by sending it as a GET param.

For eg:

```
class Multiply {
    public int factor = 5;

    public doMul(int n) {
        return n * factor;
    }
}
```

Suppose this is my class. I create an object of this class for every request and call the doMul function with the use supplied value of n. I want to build a generic framework where the user can send a GET param to override the value of this factor for a particular request (example format being "?n=10&factor=2").

What would be a good design for this use case? On option i can think of is to read values of pre-defined params like 'factor' and then use if-else to set the instance variable. Is there something more generic to be used here?

Answer (score 0):

You **could** add a function to mutate `factor`, but then you would have to mutate it back before calling it with the default. I would suggest making `factor` a parameter and adding a default for the current form of the API. Also, you forgot the return type `int` on the `doMul` function. Like,

```
class Multiply {
    public int doMul(int n) {
        return doMul(n, 5);
    }

    public int doMul(int n, int factor) {
        return n * factor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am coming from a pov where i have many such classes and each class may have 4-5 such member variables. I was hoping to support an API where the user can send 'MyClass.myVar=Value' in get param and i can set it without explicit parsing. maybe something using reflection?

Comment: Reflection is much more complex than explicit parsing, and I'm not at all sure what you think parsing the value is the difficult part.

Comment: i wouldn't say parsing them is "difficult", just more explicit if the number of such variables is a lot. But i get what you mean, should not be doing anything clever here :)